# Fibonacci in MIPS assembly doesn't return correct answer

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to implement the fibonacci function in the MIPS assembly language. I have written some code below and at it passes runtime execution without any errors, and I can see the n value in $a0 correctly ticks down at each iteration. However, the result placed in $v0 is never set until the very last iteration, where it returns 2

code:

```
data: 
    addi $a0, $zero, 10

fib: 
    slti $t0, $a0, 2     # check n <= 1
    beq $t0, $zero, body # if previous statement was false, continue procedure
    addi $v0, $zero, 1   # else return 1

    jr $ra               # return to body


body:
    addi $sp, $sp, -16 # make room for 4 registers in stack
    sw $a0, 0($sp)     # save $a0 = n, to stack
    sw $ra, 4($sp)     # save return address to stack

    addi $a0, $a0, -1  # $a0 =  n - 1
    jal fib            # invoke fib(n-1) and save return address

    sw $v0, 8($sp)     # $v0 = fib(n-1), save to stack

    addi $a0, $a0, -1  # $a0 = n - 2
    jal fib            # invoke fib(n-2) and save return address

    sw $v0, 12($sp)    # $v0 = fib(n-2), save to stack

    lw $t0, 8($sp)     # $t0 = fib(n-1)
    lw $t1, 12($sp)    # $t1 = fib(n-2)
    addi $sp, $sp, 16  # pop from stack

    add $v0, $t0, $t1  # $v0 = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

    syscall            # return
```

Comment: What is your question? Which line is not doing what you expected?

Comment: The problem is that for all inputs > 2, the result stored in $v0 at termination is 2, and I'm not sure the exact line

Comment: Well, then you need to debug some more. When you get to the point that some line is not doing what you expect, come back and we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your ABI, the stack pointer should point to the first *empty* address on the stack, so lines like

```
sw $a0, 0($sp)     # save $a0 = n, to stack
```

should be avoided, in case your program gets interrupted on a system where the interrupt handler uses the user stack.

The bigger problem with your code is the way your function returns when it was called with `n>1`:

```
syscall            # return
```

is simply wrong. You don't `syscall` to return! This is especially puzzling, since you use

```
jr $ra               # return to body
```

correctly in the `n<=1` case.

Instead of `syscall`, you need to use

```
lw   $ra, 4($sp)     #restore link register
addi $sp, $sp, 16    #restore stack pointer
jr   $ra             #return
```